# Consulta a dos tablas en .php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo una consulta a dos tablas relacionadas. En la tabla1 tengo todos los usuarios y en la tabla2 están las referencias de los usuarios y la fecha de los que han realizado con fecha de HOY un pedido. Hay usuarios que HOY no han realizado pedidos. Quiero obtener todos los usuarios. Los que hoy han hecho pedidos debe aparecer la fecha de hoy, los que HOY NO han hecho pedidos, DEBEN APARECER POR EJEMPLO CON UN guión o un asterisco (-, *).

```
$hoy = date("j, n, Y"); 

$query_search = "select * from tabla1 t1, tabla2 t2 WHERE t1.ref=t2.ref AND t2.fecha_pedido LIKE'%{$hoy}%'";
```

de esta manera solo obtengo los usuarios que han realizado un pedido hoy, pero no los que no lo han hecho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que las tablas estan relacionadas entonces lo que puedes hacer en un left join y un case algo asi:

```
$query_search = "SELECT 
                     CASE
                         WHEN tabla2.fecha_pedido = NULL THEN "El usuario no compro el dia de hoy" ELSE "El usuario compro el dia de hoy"
                     END 
                 FROM tabla1 
                 LEFT JOIN tabla2 ON tabla1.ref = tabla2.ref 
                 WHERE DATE(tabla2.fecha_pedido) = DATE(NOW())";
```

En este caso podria funcionar sin embargo seria de mucha ayuda conocer un poco de tu diagrama entidad relación o de como tienes relacionadas ambas tablas para determinar como generar la consulta exacta que necesitas.

## EDICIÓN

Considerando que la tabla 1 va a tener todos los registros de los clientes entonces debemos obtener primero todos los datos de estos, despues obtenemos todos los datos de los clientes que han hecho compras el dia de hoy y juntamos ambas consultas con un `LEFT JOIN` esto nos va a dar una lista completa de todos los usuarios independientemente de si hay o no compra en el dia resultando en la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT 
    A.ref,IFNULL(B.fecha, "-")
FROM
    (
        SELECT ref FROM tabla1;
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN
    ( 
        SELECT tabla2.ref AS ref,tabla2.fecha AS fecha FROM  tabla2
        INNER JOIN  tabla1 ON tabla1.ref = tabla2.ref
        WHERE DATE(tabla2).fecha = DATE(NOW())
    )B ON A.ref = B.ref
```

Comment: En este caso un cliente puede realizar uno o muchos pedidos. No me funciona esta consulta. También he probado IFNULL(tabla2.fecha_pedido, 0), pero sin resultados.

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste hacer un UNION? algo asi como `SELECT * FROM tabla1 UNION SELECT * FROM tabla2  WHERE tabla2.fecha_pedido = ...` creo que eso podria funcionar, si te es posible sube nada mas que datos se estan relacionando en las dos tablas para determinar como se haria una consulta mas limpia

Comment: Los datos que se relacionan son ref, en la tabla1 existe un cliente, si hace un pedido hoy aparece su ref en la tabla2 junto con la fecha y tipo de pedido. Lo que necesito es mostrar todos los clientes mostrando la fecha de hoy sí han hecho un pedido o un guión si no lo han hecho hoy.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, revisala y si esta lista entonces fue un gusto ayudarte de lo contrario me complaceria seguir haciendolo

Comment: Perfecto Ivan, muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente que bueno que te funciono :D